# Jquery popup not opening rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, popup

I am trying to load pop up when I click on share link but it is not opening I don't know where I am making mistake

I am following this tutorial and struck at step 12
[http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940]

 [index.html.erb]

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %> 
   <h1>Welcome to ShareBox</h1> 
   <p>File sharing web application you can't ignore.</p> 




<% else %> 
   <div id="menu"> 
       <ul id= "top_menu">     



      <% if @current_folder %>
          <li><%= link_to "Upload", new_sub_file_path(@current_folder) %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "New Folder", new_sub_folder_path(@current_folder) %></li>

        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Upload", new_asset_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "New Folder", new_folder_path %></li>
        <% end %>   

       </ul> 
    </div> 

        <%= render :partial => "breadcrumbs" %>

   <div class="asset_list_header"> 
       <div class="file_name_header">File Name</div> 
       <div class="file_size_header">Size</div> 
       <div class="file_last_updated_header">Modified</div> 
   </div> 


   <div class="asset_list"> 

    <!-- Listing Folders -->
<% @folders.each do |folder| %> 

  <div class="asset_details folder">     


        <div class="file_name"><%= link_to folder.name, browse_path(folder) %></div> 
        <div class="file_size">-</div> 
        <div class="file_last_updated">-</div> 
        <div class="action"> 

           <div class="share"> 
                 <div id="open">

            <%= link_to "Share" ,"#", :folder_id => folder.id, :folder_name => folder.name  %>
            </div>

          </div>

            <div class="rename"> 
                <%= link_to "Rename", rename_folder_path(folder) %> 
            </div> 
            <div class="delete"> 


               <%= button_to 'destroy', folder_path(folder), :confirm => 'Are you sure to delete the folder and all of its contents?', :method=>:delete %>

            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
<% end %>
<!-- listing files -->      
       <% @assets.each do |asset| %> 
       <div class="asset_details file"> 
       <div class="file_name"><%= link_to asset.file_name, download_url(asset) %></div> 
       <div class="file_size"><%= number_to_human_size(asset.file_size, :precision => 2) %></div> 
       <div class="file_last_updated"><%= asset.uploaded_file_updated_at %></div> 
       <div class="action"> 
           <div class="download"> 
               <%= link_to "Download" ,download_url(asset) %> 
           </div> 
           <div class="delete"> 

                   <%= button_to 'destroy', folder_path(asset), :confirm => 'Are you sure to delete the folder and all of its contents?', :method=>:delete %>
           </div> 
       </div> 
   </div> 
<% end %>

   </div> 

  <div id="invitation_form" title="Invite others to share" style="display:none">
    <% form_tag '/home/share' do -%>
        <label for="email_addresses">Enter recipient email addresses here</label><br />
        <%= text_field_tag 'email_addresses', "", :class => 'text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'%>
        <br /><br />
        <label for="message">Optional message</label><br />
        <%= text_area_tag 'message',"",  :class => 'text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'%>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "folder_id" %>
    <% end -%>        
  </div>

<% end %>
```

[home controller]

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController 

  def index 
    if user_signed_in? 
     @folders = current_user.folders.roots        
     @assets = current_user.assets.where("folder_id is NULL").order("uploaded_file_file_name desc")       
    end
end



def browse 
    #get the folders owned/created by the current_user 
    @current_folder = current_user.folders.find_by_id(params[:folder_id])   

    if @current_folder

      #getting the folders which are inside this @current_folder 
      @folders = @current_folder.children 

      #We need to fix this to show files under a specific folder if we are viewing that folder 
      @assets = current_user.assets.order("uploaded_file_file_name desc") 

      render :action => "index"
    else
      flash[:error] = "You cannot acces other ppl folder"
      redirect_to root_url 
    end

end
end
```

[application.js]

```
$(function () { 
    //open the invitation form when a share button is clicked
    $( ".share a" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {

                //assign this specific Share link element into a variable called "a"
                var a = this;

                //First, set the title of the Dialog box to display the folder name
                $("#invitation_form").attr("title", "Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others" );

                //a hack to display the different folder names correctly
                $("#ui-dialog-title-invitation_form").text("Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others"); 

                //then put the folder_id of the Share link into the hidden field "folder_id" of the invite form
                $("#folder_id").val($(a).attr("folder_id"));


                //the dialog box customization
                $( "#invitation_form" ).dialog({
                    height: 300,
                    width: 600,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        //First button
                        "Share": function() {
                            //get the url to post the form data to
                            var post_url = $("#invitation_form form").attr("action");

                            //serialize the form data and post it the url with ajax
                            $.post(post_url,$("#invitation_form form").serialize(), null, "script");

                            return false;
                        },
                        //Second button
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    },
                    close: function() {

                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
});
```

Comment: Try to change "$( ".share a" ).button().click(function()" to "$( ".share a" ).click(function()"

Comment: Not working when I am clicking on it pop up is not opening

Comment: Use this one: 
$( "body" ).on("click", ".share a", function() {...code...});

Comment: not working still nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you implement the click event is wrong. Consider changing it to

```
$( "body" ).on("click", ".share a", function() {...
```

If you load content asynchronously, then default .click event will not work, you have to use .on method to bind the event to control you generated asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$( "body" ).on("click", ".share a", function() {...code...});
```

I hope it'll help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Just print the the alert("hello") message inside the code like: 

$( "body" ).on("click", ".share a", function() { alert('hello'); });

check is it work or not.

Comment: let me show you my scripts which are there maybe there are conflicting

Comment: okay. If alert message is not pop-up then for sure there is some confliction in your js files.

Comment: yeah so how can I can resolve that problem even I have posted my jquery files

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/pipeline_assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/assets.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/controls.self-ab2e2fa469e30fcd7a69ff0fdf510bf7fd037396e9fb3e77c84af11b60aff548.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/dragdrop.self-36431046ae5f9e21ecda6df33f8c0c4eb27662780cef6fca6f29c93ce550e00b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/effects.self-dd03ea45ac506c542f4130304d3f8a78ebcd0a10996add7a0896665d0a1a7346.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/folders.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/jquery-1.4.4.min.self-4f26ef985d523b47553f38a0e8ff3084dbeb3d177a1df62ccf650ecd288d2c8f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.self-7ca2e56d842202968964bce8796efe4b122f989de0e317e9a8815a3721e36547.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/jquery.rails.self-b53727dd8652853e07923b1d5c99755df923482448e4e0f869b988f51af34af0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/prototype.self-a25a23744532b0eed575efd9fe88f42d7f042ed73e3abdb0911748b63e217d5c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/rails.self-7fa7e1dfd72cae11fff2095dd6171afc6fafbfb76f4668873445883a71287dcc.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/scriptaculous.self-6845f707fc3579647bbe9b48f10a86c8edc7a7f564af9a7465832a2577ec1fdd.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/social-share-button.self-d1725d35699d974c9834cae2be205aae782d1dc63fe9d4cebcfce8146bf2e71a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/pipeline_assets/application.self-29d8065068110d1c25667fc41416f8a3216af60ecde3cb52fe0095c720578d84.js?body=1"></script>
```

Comment: These are all of my scripts

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to change your class share into

```
$( ".share a" )
```

into

```
$( "#open a" )
```

Or if you think that `div open` doesn't need, you can remove it because in it's nothing in the tutorial.

```
<div class="share">
  <%= link_to "Share" ,"#", :folder_id => folder.id, :folder_name => folder.name  %>
</div>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Sorry not working ..when I click on share in URL a # is embedded and nothing else happens

Comment: Can you put alert inside your javascript to check it works or not? Does it show the alert?

Comment: You can use this `$( ".share a" ).bind("click", function(){ //your code });`. But before you implement this, you have to delete `open` div like my answer above. Then please show me the console browser error when it doesn't work.

Comment: I think some problem is in jquery files ...I have application.js  , assets.coffee , controls.js , dragdrop.js  effects.js , folders.coffee , jquery-1.4.4.min.js , jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js , jquery.rails.js , prototype.js , rails.js , scriptaculous.js , users.coffee

Comment: hey now I am getting error in console actually I was viewing in mozilla but now in chrome     Uncaught controls.js requires including script.aculo.us' effects.js library
dragdrop.self-36431046ae5f9e21ecda6df33f8c0c4eb27662780cef6fca6f29c93ce550e00b.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Effect is not defined

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Effect is not defined
effects.self-dd03ea45ac506c542f4130304d3f8a78ebcd0a10996add7a0896665d0a1a7346.js?body=1:73 Uncaught ReferenceError: Prototype is not defined
application.self-5514ec077808f549f621bf4aa6d9d9e73ddb9ead85fc82fa757c7d9ce3fc32f1.js:73 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }